# How to Insert Object Type in ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to maintain both ID and Object Type in my ListView.  I'm trying to do this:

```
lstView.Items.Insert(MyObject);
// can't do this, because it takes only Int and String
```

In my case, the ID is int, so that part is ok.  But how to insert an object type and retrieve it in the Item_Selection changed event?

Comment: If you can't do it, then you can't do it.  Maybe there's a workaround- what's your goal here?

Comment: Please don't prefix your questions with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A `ListView` cannot add or insert an object directly like a `ListBox` or `ComboBox`, but instead you need to create a `ListViewItem` and set its `Tag` property.

The Tag property from Msdn

> An Object that contains data about the control. The default is null.
>
> Any type derived from the Object class can be assigned to this
>   property. If the Tag property is set through the Windows Forms
>   designer, only text can be assigned.   A common use for the Tag
>   property is to store data that is closely associated with the control.
>   For example, if you have a control that displays information about a
>   customer, you might store a DataSet that contains the customer's order
>   history in that control's Tag property so the data can be accessed
>   quickly.

Example code:

```
MyObject myObj = new MyObject();

ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = myObj.ToString(); // Or whatever display text you need
item.Tag = myObj;

// Setup other things like SubItems, Font, ...

listView.Items.Add(item);
```

When you need to get your object back from the `ListView`, you can cast the `Tag` property.

```
private void OnListViewItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    MyObject myObj = (MyObject)e.Item.Tag;
    int id = myObj.Id;

    // Can access other MyObject Members
}
```

Usually its easier to wrap the functionality into a helper method.

```
public static void CreateListViewItem(ListView listView, MyObject obj) {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Tag = obj;

    // Other requirements as needed

    listView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And you can do:

```
CreateListViewItem(listView, obj);
```

A `ListView` doesn't support a `DataSource` property like a lot of controls, so if you wish to data bind you will need to implement something a bit more custom.

Comment: There is global rule I use: Instead of using Tag property, extend control adding new property

Answer (score 2):

Create new listviewitem object. use Tag property.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way around this is to keep a list of your object on the side:

```
List<MyObject> list = ... ; // my list
```

Generate a dictionary from the list with a string as the ID, or you can use the index to retrieve from the original list:

```
Dictionary<int,string> listBinder = new Dictionary<int,string>(
    list.Select(i => new KeyValuePair<int,string>(i.ID, i.Name))
);
```

Bind or codebehind attaching the listview to the dictionary, then use the selected item to retrieve your object from your private list.